# Удаление дубликатов python

Tags: python, список

Есть код (не мой):

```
list = [1,4,2,3,4,5,6]
result = []
for i in list:
    if i not in result:
        result.append(i)
print(result)
```

Я не понимаю, почему `i` добавляется в `result` без дубликатов. Да, код работает как надо, но я не понимаю почему дубликаты удаляются, какая строчка или строчки конкретно делают так чтобы список `result` был без дубликатов?

P.S Если можете объясните каждую строку кода.

Comment: Ну так условие if стоит, что если числа нет в результате, то добавлять его в результат. Соответственно, если число встретилось повторно, то  и уже добавлялось в результат, то повторно не добавится.

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Дубликаты не удаляются. Они просто не переносятся в result, так как не выполняется условие в 4 строке.